# String Search Android

Tags: android, string

I have a ListView with some info like Eifell Tower, Louvre and places like that. What i want to do is to search on Wikipedia and Youtube for this text. For instance i click on Louvre and than an i have the option to choose to search on wiki or on youtube.
 I already create the two options to search in wiki and you. But i don't know the code to search using for instance the string "Louvre" and use to search in wikipedia and youtube.
 Also i have to make a webview to cover this up.

Thanks and sorry for my English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To search on wikipedia/youtube, you can use their respective search urls:

### wikipedia:

#### http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=***searchterms***

where `searchterms` is of the form: *term1+term2+...*

Example search for html ide:

[`http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=html+ide`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=html%20ide)

### Youtube:

#### http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=***searchterms***

same thing as wikipedia for `searchterms`.

Example search for android tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=android+tutorial

### WebView:

To create a webview: [*http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html*](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html)

To open url from within your application: [*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/android-open-url-from-code*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/android-open-url-from-code)

Comment: Well, what i want to select a from a  listView and search it on youtube or on wikipedia. How i do that?