# Android : Open a URL in a Browser

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I open a URL in Android’s web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

I've been trying to find out how to create an intent that will open the specified URL in a Specified browser. Browser may not always be the default one. 
But i am unable to do so.

Answer (score 20):

Use the Intent.ACTION_VIEW constant as Intent action and the url as data.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Note the URL must be a full URL (starting with either http:// or https://) so check in your code that the URL is not a short form such as www.google.com if it is user-defined.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
String url = "your URL";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: -1 Use the Intent.ACTION_VIEW constant

Comment: if someone tried to help , people votes -1 , :) , that's a good thing ^^ , just for information :  the code above is working fine for me ,

Comment: Help always appreciated :) Constants always better than strings too.

Comment: Working code does not mean it should be encouraged (the -1 is simply pointing at something I feel incorrect). Always prefer existing constants to hardcoded values. (Constant should not be within the double quotes in your edited answer).

Comment: you can simply edit it to fixe that .... problem of quotes :)

Comment: But this will open the URL in the default browser, suppose i have opera mini installed and i want to open the URL with opera mini, what should i do ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of them, also read the [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW)

```
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")); 
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

or

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
i.setData(Uri.parse(url)); startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Do not encourage the use of hardcoded values when the appropriate constant exists somewhere. That code might break in the future.

Comment: @MarvinLabs : Ok, Thnx. I will keep it in mind. Very useful suggestion.