# how to: download and open a pdf file programmatically via http connection

Tags: android, pdf, file-io, download

how to: download (via an http connection) and open or save a pdf file programmatically.

Say I have a button on my screen and the url to the pdf, when the button is clicked I want to download the pdf from the url and have the user presented with the choice to open or save the file.  There must be a standard way to do something so commonplace, should I open the browser to the url or can I do this from my app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("*url for your pdf*"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

This will cause the pdf to be downloaded in the notification bar, as if you had initiated the download through the browser.

Check this question if you have problems: [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Comment: Looks good, downloads the file but can I have an option to open once downloaded?  Otherwise people will have to exit my app to open the file in the downloads folder.

Comment: PS: ok, they can get at em through the notification bar like you imoplied.  Hey, its my first app and first android, am I expected to know what I'm doing?  ;)
Thanks