# WebView - load links in external browser

Tags: android, webview

I am loading the content of a locally stored `HTML` file in a `WebView` in my app. This file also contains links inside it, which when clicked, load the `URLs` in the same `WebView`. I want to load these links in an external browser instead. I have taken a look at `onPageStarted` and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, but they don't seem to work. I have tried the following:

```
    webAbout = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvAbout);
    webAbout.loadUrl(Const.defURL);

    webAbout.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
          @Override  
          public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){  
            if (!url.startsWith(Const.defURL)) { 
              view.stopLoading();  
              // DO SOMETHING  
            }else{
                view.loadUrl(Const.defURL);
            }
          }  
        });
```

I have also tried:

```
    webAbout = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvAbout);
    webAbout.loadUrl(Const.defURL);

     webAbout.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url != null && (url.startsWith(Const.defURL))){

                webAbout.loadUrl(Const.defURL);
                return true;
                } 

          else  {

                view.getContext().startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));  
                return false;
          }
        }
    });
```

but in both cases, the `WebView` does not load anything. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Return `false` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` when you want the URL loaded in the WebView, return `true` if you don't want the WebView to load the URL (that means you've somehow handled it yourself).

Remember that:

- you need to set the `WebViewClient` *before* calling `loadUrl`,
- `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is *not* called for the URL that's passed to `loadUrl`.

The code you had should work with some modifications:

```
 webAbout.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url != null && (url.startsWith(Const.defURL))){
            return false;
        } else  {
            view.getContext().startActivity(
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));  
            return true;
      }
    }
});
// I'm assuming Const.defURL doesn't need escaping.
String customHtml = "<html><body><a href=\"" + Const.defURL + "\">Load url in webview</a><a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/\">load in browser</a></body></html>";
// Here you would normally load your page using loadUrl, 
webAbout.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

**Edit**: The method `boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, String)` is marked as deprecated and the documentation recommends using `boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, WebRequest)` instead. **But**, the new method is never called. You still have to override `boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, String)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvAbout);
String url="";
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

or write this condition

```
if (urlPath
                .compareToIgnoreCase(Const.defURL) == 0) {

        } else {
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.clearView();
                    view.loadUrl(url);

                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your second method to this:

```
webAbout = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvAbout);
webAbout.loadUrl(Const.defURL);

 webAbout.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){    
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url != null && (url.startsWith(Const.defURL))){
            view.loadUrl(url);  //use new url instead of const.defURL
            return true;
        } else  {
            //use browser
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
      }
    }
});
```

taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8541631/2829009

Comment: Hmm. Tried this. But it doesn't seem to be working. :(

Comment: edited... loadUrl now loads the new url instead of the defined defURL