# How to open extarnal url in default browser and all internal links in WebView Android?

Tags: android, webview

I use this logic that every internal link contains 'myurl' string so it should be open in WebView and other external link in default browser.

```
package com.package.webviewapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        String url = "http://myurl.com";
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);

    }
}
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains("myurl")){ // Could be cleverer and use a regex
            view.loadUrl(url); // Stay within this webview and load url
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url); // Leave webview and use browser
        }
    }
}
```

but it is opening all links in WebView. as it is mentioned here [Open link from Android Webview in normal browser as popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540343/open-link-from-android-webview-in-normal-browser-as-popup) it should work.

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: @ChiragSavsani all links are opening in webview.

Comment: Have you used <meta-data> tag to differentiate between ur own url and other url.

Comment: @Rollno1 i am just a newbie in android development it is my first experience with android and java so don't how to try other logic.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to load other url use below method , it will open in default browser

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(download_link));
startActivity(myIntent);
```