# Browser activity not starting in android

Tags: android, http, browser, uri

I am making an android app. I want to open a url sent to me by the server in my app in a browser. I am retrieving the url properly. But when i try to open the url using the following code :

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri
                            .parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
```

It does not work. I get an exception stating Exception : "No activity found to handle Intent". The url is proper. If i print the url i get it properly as in it starts with "https://" and all, but when i pass the url to the browser activity it dosent work. This is a pretty weird issue. Please help me.  I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application) too, but in vain :(
- Thanks in advance

Comment: If i put the link directly it works for me, but not otherwise.

Comment: I think the problem might be with the secure content. Can you please try with some http url?

Comment: No, the problem is not with the https. I checked it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. Actually the problem was with the url. I was getting the url from some other activity, the problem was that in the url itself i had double quotes. I couldnt figure out the problem because when i was printing the string it came proper with the double quotes, but i didnt know that the string had double quotes in it.