# I need to create an Android APK with web link

Tags: android, sdk, apk

I have a client who simply needs a link installed on their Android. I need to create an APK file for them to navigate to on their phone. Then, when clicked, needs to simply install a link icon on their phone's desktop. After install, the new icon link needs to link to a url I declare in the APK file. I'm sure this is very simple but I'm new to Android SDK and my client is in a jam... any help is MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If all you really want to do is add a link to a URL on the home screen then you might want to consider just adding a bookmark to the home screen instead of creating an Android app.  Google "android bookmark home screen" and you will get the instructions such as this, http://philwilson.org/blog/2010/01/adding-a-bookmark-to-an-android-home-screen.

If you actually do want to proceed with writing an Android app for some reason then what you need to do is create one single Activity with a WebView control on it.  Then you just load your URL using the loadUrl method of WebView.  See the sample code on this link, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html.

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
webview.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many existing questions that basically address this. All you're looking to do is start the browser. Take a look at this question: [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

As for when to do that, you want to do it at launch. Since ALL you want to do is launch this URL, you'll want to use an [AliasActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AliasActivity.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a basic app using Eclipse with the ADK plugin.

For the code you can simply add something such as:

```
public class MyApp extends Activity {

WebView wb;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main );
    wb = new WebView(this);
    wb.loadUrl("http://www.link.com");
    setContentView(wb);
}
}
```

Once installed you can just drag the icon onto the main screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get an apk file for any url using this website http://www.appsgeyser.com/ 
No code will be generated. only apk file will be generated which can be installed on a device.