# Android : Intent twitter uri

Tags: android, twitter, android-intent

In my android application I want to redirect the users to my twitter profile page and I use this code :

```
Inrent i : new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(''https://www.twitter.com/MYUSER));
startActivity(i);
```

If I choose the browser it work fine but if I choose twitter application it show a Toast "Impossible to.complete the action". How can I resolve this problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing the `setData()` method:

```
String url = "http://twitter.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Please read more here: [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Let me know if this helps!