# Can I link my website to a menu item on the android menu?

Tags: android, android-intent, menu, web, menuitem

I was wondering whether anyone could assist me. When the user clicks the menu button, on their android phone, the menu pops up. I would like to create a new menu item so that when clicked, it takes them instantly to my website. Is there any way to do this with intents or something like: ACTION_SEND?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here: [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application) -- Just put that within the onClick() event for the button.

Comment: Thank you so much. There was a perfect example on there and it worked like a charm. I appreciate your help. My website now loads from my app menu.