# Open a URL in Android's web browser from application

Tags: android

How can I open a url in the android web browser from my application on clicking a button.

I tried this :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strURL));

startActivity(myIntent);
```

but I am getting exception:

but I got an Exception :

```
 "No activity found to handle Intent{action=android.intent.action.VIEW data =www.google.com"
```

Comment: Learn more about WebViewClient.

Comment: How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2201917/1012284

Comment: add INTERNET permission in manifest file

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it fundamentally correct, you just need to include the full url.

```
String strURL="http://www.google.com";
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strURL));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Basically, the `http` is the protocol. It is the computer's way of trying to figure out how you want to open it. You might also be interested in `https`, if you want a secure connection over SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Almost seems like [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/launch-android-browser/) would be useful to read... from the page:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://androidbook.blogspot.com");
Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(launchBrowser);
```

There is a second way, involving the [WebView](http://j.mp/bsWWyA), but that seems like it's not your question. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Your answer would be considerably better if you could explain _why_ you think this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String strURL = "http://www.google.com";
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strURL));

        startActivity(myIntent);
```

As for the missing "http://" I'd just do something like this:

```
if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
   url = "http://" + url;
```