# How to open a specific browser from an android app

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser

I want to open a url in a browser from an Android app.  Thats pretty straightforward: [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

But how can I open the url in a specific browser, if it exists.

```
if(user has chrome)
    open url in chrome;
else if(user has opera)
    open url in opera;
else
    open url in default browser;
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking Tanis right, you shouldn't do such things for Android.

However, if you really need to. You can use [Intent.setPackage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage%28java.lang.String%29). This will send indent to appropriate application package.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't force the user to use a specific application for a generic event like opening a URL. Android is designed to give the user the freedom to use whatever app they want.

This is why when you click URLs on your phone, you will get a dialog asking which application you want to use for that action. You can select an application to always handle that type of action, but apps should not choose for you.