# Android push notification opening a custom page

Tags: android, html, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

my question for you is the following: I have a web app written in HTML5, wrapped as a native Android app in order to use Google Push Notifications. Because my app is using many notifications for different reasons, I want to be able to say each time a notification is received, which page to be open, like adding a 'href' in the notification intent. Is this possible?
If I wasn't clear enough please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own notification message content. The Message builder from Google supports key value pairs to be set by the sender of the notification.
See http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/server/Message.html

Example:

```
Message message = new Message.Builder()
    .addData("link1", "http://mypage1.com")
    .addData("link2", "http://mypage2.com")
    .build();
```

Comment: I am already using this so I can know every notification arriving what type is it. But once the notification arrives, I don't know how I open a certain webview of my app. I suppose there's something to do with the Intent object, I'm still searching.

Comment: You can start the Android browser with the url or start your own activity containing a webview. 
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application

Answer (score 0):

When you create the notification, use [setContentIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29) to attach an Intent that has been constructed to visit the right webpage:

```
// assuming <this> is an Activity or other Context
Intent urlIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(yourUrl));
PendingIntent urlPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 urlIntent, 0);
Notification.Builder b = new Notification.Builder(this)
   .setSmallIcon(...).setContentTitle(...).setContentText(...) // etc.
   .setContentIntent(urlPendingIntent);
NotificationManager noMan
    = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
noMan.notify(ID, b.build());
```

If you expect to have more than one of these in the notification panel at a time:

1. Reconsider. It's spammy to post more than one notification.
2. If you must, you'll need a separate ID (or separate tag) for each.