# Creating an android app that simply launches a URL in the browser

Tags: android

I happen to have a mobile-friendly web app, but my users desperately want to install it to their app drawer :/ I have some experience with Java, the new Android Studio, and I see some instructions on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application), but I'm unsure where this code belongs:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Putting it in the `onCreate` method of the default action yields errors that suggest that's the wrong place for an intent. Where would be a good place to execute such an intent?

Comment: did you import the Intent class in your Activity?

Comment: what are the "yields errors that suggest that's the wrong place for an intent"?

Comment: The better thing would be to include a WebView in your layout and launch the webpage in that instead of the browser and intent. creating an app just to launch a webpage on launch is pretty useless IMO

Comment: @silverback I found plenty of tutorials helping to do that, but I am really designing a web app and want the latest browser capabilities to be present. I agree that it's useless- just as useless as native apps in the first place :-P The only reason I'm doing an app at all is for my app-minded users who don't know how else to launch anything on their phone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Your reference, i tried this code,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

}
```

In Manifest's xml (e.g. `AndroidManifest.xml`) add

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="...">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application ...>
      ...

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Aha, I wasn't importing enough things- Needed Uri and Intent. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the `setContentView()` if you just want to fire the Intent

Comment: @dtmilano: i accept your point, but i was tried this sample app with Button click,