# When user click on alert button open mobile browser and display URL on android

Tags: java, android

When user click on alert massage know more button open mobile browser and display URL of my website on android apps what I have made.I need the code. I have tried many code like web view and others, but not working. Please help me!

Comment: please share what you have tried with errors you have got.

Comment: please keep in mind this is alert popup massage not a simple button.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com/"));
  startActivity(browserIntent);
```

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I coded sth for you, dont know if this is the answer you want

```
          new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("My homepage")
            .setMessage("Wanna go to my 1337 homepage?")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.my1337site.com"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
             })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://www.xyz.com"; //your URL
Intent openUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
openUrl.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(openUrl);
```

add this code on the onclick of the Alert box

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 String url = "http://www.example.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
```