# Newbies Creating Shortcut to URL App for Android

Tags: android, apk

I'm a complete newbie in creating an app for Android.

What I need could be very simple if someone could help me out.

I want to create an *.apk file which can be downloaded from the market by the user and installs a shortcut to a single URL (mobile web).

I've heard about Intent() or such a like. But I don't know where to start, which programs to use and how to compile this small app which on click opens the default browser on android and opens the specified URL.

Just looking for the basic settings like, icon for the app, install app, create icon on home screen, connect to the URL.

Many thanks for any help or tutorials.

Comment: Please take some time to read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) so you can understand Android.

Comment: Start here http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application) link.