# Implicit Intent to view URL

Tags: android

I am new to Android, I want to create an Intent to view google website. My String is declared as follows:

```
static private final String URL = "http://www.google.com";
```

and my Intent :

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:+URL"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

This code shows no errors in Eclipse, but I think it might be wrong.

Comment: it might? have you tested it? What is the result?

Comment: "geo:+URL" is completely wrong. That is just a string, you're not really using your static field here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not building your Uri correctly, when trying to concatenate 2 String, use this :

```
String s = "I'm a string variable";

String concatenated = s + " and I'm another String variable";
```

Now the content of concatenated is

> I'm a string variable and I'm another String variable

If you do this :

```
String concatenated = "s + and I'm another String variable";
```

the content of concatenated is

> s + and I'm another String variable

Secondly, why are you using a geo Uri ? This is for viewing locations. To view a website, just use the URL (and don't forget the "http://" part) :

```
String URL = "http://www.google.com";
browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(URL));
```

Comment: No, you should not leave out the http part, or will end up with an error, use browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.com")); Have a look at this question for details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application?rq=1

Comment: browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(URL));    i've put it like this

Comment: Mmmh, looks like SO comments system is hiding the http part, sorry, I didn't know about that, just noticed mine was cut as well :) Using Uri.parse(URL) will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an intent and then set data for it. Intent also has a constructor that takes action String and data URI.

Also you need to use `geo:` when you want to show something on a map. So view an URL in browser you can simply use the website URL. You can pass it to `Uri.parse()` method to get URI object needed in the intents constructor. 
You can simply do -

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
Intent browserChooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(browserIntent , "Choose browser of your choice");
startActivity(browserChooserIntent );
```

Answer (score 0):

2Dee's answer is correct. You can also give the action and set data uri in a single line. To view the website.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent browserIntent=null, chooser=null;
    browserIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    chooser = browserIntent.createChooser(intent,"Open Website Using...");
    if(browserIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        startActivity(chooser);
    }
```