# Android - unable to start activity componentinfo error while using Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent

I added a function which is "if click the element of list, then execute the browser app". Press home button and execute another app while running the browser app. And the problem is when return to my app, the error "unable to start activity componentinfo" is occurred.

I'm sorry my english is weak.

My app is using ViewPager and Fragment.

The problem step.

1. My app: Click the element of list

   `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));`

   `startActivity(intent);`
2. Browser: Press Home button
3. Home: Execute another app
4. Another app: Press Home button
5. Home: Execute My app
6. the error is occurred

Log

```
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.temp.example/com.temp.example.Main}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.temp.example.Temp: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:997)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.temp.example.Temp: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:413)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1790)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:213)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at com.temp.example.Main.onCreate(Main.java:58)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5177)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    ... 11 more
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.temp.example.Temp; no empty constructor
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
03-25 22:26:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(28894):    ... 18 more
```

If you know the solution, please let me know.

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Please provide some code and stacktrace so we can help you...

Comment: Edit Your Question With log errors

Comment: Thanks. I added some details.

Answer (score 1):

Visit that Tutorial
[How To Open An URL In Android’s Web Browser](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-open-an-url-in-androids-web-browser/)

or follow that Question [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can open browser. My problem is when the browser is running, execute another app and then re-execute to my app, the error is occurred.