# How to open link in external browser in cocos 2d-x

Tags: ios, url, cocos2d-x, uiapplication, cocos2d-x-3.0

I was opening link in cocos 2d-x (in Previous versions) like:

```
CCApplication::sharedApplication()->openUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

A help from this link:

```
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/4893/files
```

But in new version openUrl no more exist.

So how can i open links now in new version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which OS are you targeting specifically, 
you can try writing Obj-C code for iOS and put it in

```
#ifdef (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];  
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

    #endif
```

and add complier flag obj-c and c++ on source file

Similarly, on android you can make JNI call
(Java Code)

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("<link>"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

On how to call jni from cocos2d-x
http://purplelilgirl.tumblr.com/post/54583532324/code-bit-how-to-use-jni-in-cocos2dx-android

Referred from
[How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)