# external link cordova not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, inappbrowser

working on a small app using `codova` im tryign to open link on browser, but this is not working I don;t know why, it only opens in `webview`.

```
 <a href='#' onclick='openURL("http://google.com")'/>LInka</a> 
 <a href='#' onclick='window.open("http://google.com", '_system')'/>LInka</a>

    function openURL(urlString){
        myURL = encodeURI(urlString);
        window.open(myURL, '_blank');
    }
```

Comment: Might this helps you [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Comment: @Satpal thank im looking at that answer but i can't understand it

Comment: I would replace apostrophies on `'_system'` to quotes `"_system"`. You encapsulate the `onclick` event function with `'` apostrophies but the first apostrophie on `'_system'` ends the encapsulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem, are including you the cordova.js on your page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" /> 
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<a onclick="navigator.app.loadUrl('yourwebsite.com', { openExternal:true });">Links</a>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
function openURL(urlString){
    myURL = encodeURI(urlString);
    window.open(myURL, '_blank');
}
</script>
```

try creating a new project and make sure index.html looks like this
don't need to include inappbrowser
Good luck hope it helps