# Open Twitter URL with app, instead of browser

Tags: android, ios, twitter, deep-linking

I've got the following URL:

```
http://twitter.com/share?url=http://example.com"
```

When clicked on iOS and Android, it opens the browser window. What's the best way to open this with the app (if they have it installed)?

EDIT:

I've changed the URL to

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=example
```

But it still opens in the browser (I have the app installed). Does this require JavaScript or anything else to work?

Comment: Have you done it with an Intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use intents, as in [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

If the app is available the user gets to decide if the app should handle twitter URIs.

Comment: Maybe this can help you further: http://omgwtfgames.com/2012/01/android-intents-captured-by-various-twitter-clients/

Answer (score 0):

I copy the URL and paste it into the Twitter app search field. 
It works; if it doesn't, remove "mobile" from the URL (as in https://mobile.twitter.com)