# Android development: Open URL in Google Chrome in full screen mode

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent

I want to open any URL with Google Chrome from my android app. Also want to know how to set Full screen mode, if it is possible. 
I know how to do that with default android browser, from following discussion:

[How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Code:

`Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);`