# Redirect automatic in app using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, redirect, android-webview

I am new to Eclipse and androids app.

I want a simple app to Androids phones.
User starts this app and will directly been redirected to my homesite www.mypage.com

Can Someone help me? I try to use Eclipse to make this..

Comment: Eclipse is IDE and really doesn't matter here ... you should learn some android basics like what is `Intent` and how to use it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Comment: Do you want to open a url / website  in your app's first screen ?

Comment: Yes Rose, i want to open a url directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new Android project . File New Android Application Project choose defaults   and then in your MainActivity  class:                                                                           @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
    // add these two lines
```

Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.mypage.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

Comment: you may need to import    these two as well                                                            import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

Comment: I get error in this line:
.add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();


PlaceholderFragment cannot be resolved to a type
container cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: control+z everything if you copied my whole code .. just copy the two last two lines inside your onCreate() method

Comment: Where can i find "onCreate()"

Is it in here:
 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {}