# Android, How to run a chrome shortcut?

Tags: android, shortcut

I created a chrome shortcut for a specific page using "Add to home screen". How can I run/start this shortcut from my app?

Comment: If chrome is default browser you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application

Comment: @TapaSave I'm using android 4.4.2 ... if I open the browser, the domain area will be shown but, if I open the shortcut it'll be full screen and that's what I want.

Comment: but apart from this ... is there a way to target a specific shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're looking to use Chrome, as per the shortcut, but if you're not looking to use intents, could you perhaps use a Webview to embed the URL / intent in? This will also hide the domain information and such.

Answer (score 0):

To open a URL/website you do the following:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Here's the documentation of [Intent.ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW).

Now if chrome is installed on the device the device will show option for default browser and chrome.