# Redirect to specific url

Tags: android, http, url, httpclient

I am fresh android developer who having limit knowledge about Android. How to redirect to the specific url no matter what url being browsed after clicking the button?

Comment: have you tried something share some code question is too broad.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2201999/3326331

Comment: Current i just develop the button only without any function including...