# Mark email link to open in web browser and not mobile app

Tags: android

I have an android app and a corresponding web app. I am trying to run an email campaign where email would contain a link which is accessible only on the web and not on mobile app. But when I try to open the link through my mobile, it attempts to open it in the mobile app and then bounces off to the email. Is there a way I can mark the link so that it is not attempted in the mobile app and is directly opened in the browser?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)?

Comment: I am not trying to open the link from my mobile app. The link is in the email - opened in email app on mobile. This link is being attempted to open in my app, but I want it to go to the web browser.

Comment: Obviously, if you are opening links from another app that is not yours, you can not alter the way that application behaves. @shreyj