# Opening browser in my application

Tags: android, android-browser

I have to open browser in my Android app. I know how it can be done but is it possible that when browser is opened and the user tries to see all the open application, my app and the browser seem to be in one or in other words browser opens within my app process. I know Webview but due to some restrictions I have to use browser window only.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use an intent? [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to answer

Comment: I don't think so, it can be done... Because browser is an internal Intent...You need to use webView instead of Browser..But as you have told that you can't use webView  because of some restriction.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to use web browsers to launch links, you can use the intent below:

```
Intent openBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.webaddress.com"));
startActivity(openBrowser);
```