# Redirect to a webpage while opening an android app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, mobile-application

I need to develop an app which redirects users to my website right after the app was started.

Thats all I want in my mobile app.

I am using **Android studio** but I am not familiar with XML. So I am stuck there. Which code should I write to do this redirection? Hope you all can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Comment: so instead of showing splash screen add a web view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to import this:

```
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.net.Uri;
```

In your MainActivity.java class, OnCreate Method you may add

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent i = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")
        );

// Starts Implicit Activity
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: this code gives me an some error :(  "Error:(16, 9) error: cannot find symbol class Intent"

Comment: you have to import Intent class
please add, above MainActivity Class.

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web view in XML file and load your url in it

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: in xml use <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

Comment: I have added the code in your answer, but it is not working, nothing happening. so my total code is like this

Comment: `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: Add this in your xml file         <WebView xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:id="@+id/webview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

Comment: and in your activity  add   code                                                               WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

Comment: Ok... you put java code in an xml file. Maybe you should try a few tutorials first.