# Button link to internet makes app crash

Tags: java, android, android-intent, buttonclick

I managed to make a navigation drawer and trying to get a button working now.

Code:

```
public class FourthFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fourth_layout, container, false);
    }
    public void buttona1(View view){
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                          Uri.parse("https://www.google.nl"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<Button
    android:text="Magister"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buttona1"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

The problem is that when I open the app in my mobile and move to the button page, push the button the app will close and stop working.

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: Did you add Internet permission to manifest?

Comment: Did you inflate the button with id in oncreateview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Comment: Just added the internet permissions to the manifest, didn't solve the problem.

Comment: is ur button initialized ?

Comment: What do you mean with initialized? When I open the app the button is there, when I click it the app fails. Where can I put the log? It is a lot and won't fit in this textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems correct but you need to make method `buttona1` in your activity
and fragment both .
You can't call the method from xml resides in Fragment but not in Activity

you may use the following code inside the `onCreateView` method

```
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fourth_layout, container, false);
    Button myButton=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
    buttona1(view)
    });
return v;
```

also replace this line

```
 startActivity(browserIntent);
```

with

```
getActivity().startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `Context` in your `fragment contsructor`  which will be passed from your `MainActivity` while initializing `freagment` and call `context.startActivity(YOUR_INTENT);`
hope this will help you