# Load a link after splash screen loads

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

I had designed splash screen in Android Studio,

I m trying to load a link or URL after the splash screens timeouts "without any button".

My Splash screen UI code looks like this

1.activity_splash

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/p1">
</RelativeLayout>
```

2. splashactivity.java

   ```
    package com.example.admin.demo1;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;


   public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

   // Splash screen timer
   private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


       setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        /*
         * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
         * want to show case your app logo / company
         */

           @Override
           public void run() {
               // This method will be executed once the timer is over
               // Start your app main activity
               Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
               startActivity(i);

               // close this activity
               finish();
           }
       }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
   }
   ```

   }
3. Mainactivity.java

   ```
    package com.example.admin.demo1;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Handler;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.Toast;
   import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
   import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;

   /*Splash screen code*/
   /*public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
   {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance_entry);

           new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
           {
               public void run()
               {
                   final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
                   MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
           }, 5000);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I think where to write code for load url after splash screen is the question right?

Answer (score 1):

If you know exactly the url just put it like that

**Mainactivity.java**

```
  package com.example.admin.demo1;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance_entry);
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(this, 
        Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com/"));
        try{
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            //No browser
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: so it will open in a webview ?

Comment: it will open in browser , if you want to create a webview inside your app you should 've put this in a question I can add some code to create a webview