# How to download selected file from google drive with DriveApi?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am using `Drive.DriveApi` and by using DriveApi able to download file but now I have upgraded play-services version i.e. `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0`  so  `Drive.DriveApi.getFile(googleApiClient, driveId)` is deprecated so please suggest any solution for it. How can download file from google drive?

My working code

```
DriveId  driveId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);

 Log.e(TAG, driveId.getResourceId() + "");

 DriveFile driveFile = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(googleApiClient, driveId);
 driveFile.getMetadata(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(metadataRetrievedCallback);
```

but now this code is deprecated with the latest update so please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I recommend you to check the [Download Files docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) in Drive API to know the underlying concepts. Then, for the implementation in Android, check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48678478/how-to-download-file-from-google-drive-with-link-in-android/48688797?noredirect=1#comment84653137_48688797).