# (Delphi 10.2) How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?

Tags: android, delphi, url, browser

**Delphi 10.2.2 Firemonkey Android Question**: How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?

I tried to understand the concepts here: [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application) but the information didn't help me any.  I am unable to wrap my brain around how they can get it to work compared to the code I currently have.

I've looked here too: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/FMX.Android_Intents_Sample

I've also looked here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html?hl=en

***I've tried this code:***

```
function OpenURL(const URL: string; const DisplayError: Boolean = False): Boolean;
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
// There may be an issue with the geo: prefix and URLEncode.
// will need to research
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW,
    TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding.URL.Encode(URL))));
  try
    TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(Intent);
    exit(true);
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
      if DisplayError then ShowMessage('Error: ' + e.Message);
      exit(false);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This is how I use that function:

```
OpenURL('https://www.patreon.com/phonelosers/overview/', true)
```

And it keeps giving me an error:

**Error: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://www.patreon.com/phonelosers/overview/ }**

***I tried this code too:***

```
function OpenURL(const URL: string; const DisplayError: Boolean = False): Boolean;
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
// There may be an issue with the geo: prefix and URLEncode.
// will need to research
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW,
    TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding.URL.Encode(URL))));
  if TAndroidHelper.Activity.getPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent, TJPackageManager.JavaClass.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size > 0 then
  begin
    try
      TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(Intent);
      exit(true);
    except
      on e: Exception do
      begin
        if DisplayError then ShowMessage('Error: ' + e.Message);
        exit(false);
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('Intent.resolveActivity <= 0');
  end;
end;
```

*which gives me "Intent.resolveActivity <= 0"*

It doesn't matter which android phone I use.  I have a Moto G Play, Samsung S8+, and a Moto Z2 Force which run Android versions 6.0.1, 7.0, 8.0.  All the phones have chrome web browser installed and I can use it.

I look all over the web and the code below is what everyone is using to supposedly do what I need it to do.  I looked at both Delphi and Android programming information.

Please help solve this Delphi 10.2.2 Firemonkey Android problem!

Answer (score 2):

After using a different coding method:

```
procedure OpenURL(const URL: string);
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
  Data: Jnet_Uri;
begin
  LIntent := TJIntent.Create;
  Data := TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(URL));
  LIntent.setData(Data);
  LIntent.setAction(StringToJString('android.intent.action.VIEW'));
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(LIntent);
end;
```

I figured out I forgot "System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding.URL.Encode" and just removing that code from the source fixed the issue so that this code:

```
function OpenURL(const URL: string; const DisplayError: Boolean = False): Boolean;
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
// There may be an issue with the geo: prefix and URLEncode.
// will need to research
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW,
    TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(URL)));
  try
    TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(Intent);
    exit(true);
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
      if DisplayError then ShowMessage('Error: ' + e.Message);
      exit(false);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

now works!

Since this *System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding.URL.Encode* has caused the issue, I'm wondering if I do need to encode my url special, what should I use?

Answer (score 1):

use this code :

```
var
  URL: string;
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  URL := 'https://www.google.com';
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW,
      TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(URL)));
  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end
```