# Open PDF file Delphi RIO

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, pascal

I would like to open a PDF that is allocated locally in my application (ANDROID only), but I am not getting it at all.

I already tried this link: [Getting exception while opening PDF file for Android 26 using Firemonkey/Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605320/getting-exception-while-opening-pdf-file-for-android-26-using-firemonkey-delphi/53605468) but not work in Delphi RIO.

So I kept looking and got this code:

```
procedure TF_NovaART.PRO_MapeaClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  fName       : String;
  LIntent: JIntent;
  LAuthority: JString;
  LUri: Jnet_Uri;
begin
    fName := TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'PRO_Topo.pdf';

    {$IFDEF ANDROID}
      LAuthority := StringToJString(JStringToString(TAndroidHelper.Context.getApplicationContext.getPackageName) + '.fileprovider');
      LUri := TJFileProvider.JavaClass.getUriForFile(TAndroidHelper.Context, LAuthority, TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(fName)));
      LIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
      LIntent.setDataAndType(LUri, StringToJString('application/pdf'));
      LIntent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
      TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(LIntent);

    {$ENDIF}

end;
```

Which was found on this link: [Getting exception while opening PDF file for Android 26 using Firemonkey/Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605320/getting-exception-while-opening-pdf-file-for-android-26-using-firemonkey-delphi/53605468)

I did exactly as it is written, but returns me the following error:

> java;lang;NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.Package
>   ItemInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager,
>   java.lang;String)' on a null object reference

now it's giving :

> java.kabg.illegalArgumentExcpetion: Failed to find configurated root
>   that contains
>   /data/data/com.embarcadero.ART_Dinamica/files/PRO_Topo.pdf.

PS: I put my pdf (PRO_Topo.pdf) in the deployment and the remote patch is ".\assets\internal"

I think I need to put in the "AndroidManifest", but I've already researched it and I'm not sure how to set it. (This bug has been stalking me for over a month. I skipped this part of the code to do other things, but again I'm unable to continue because of it)

The GIT link I got from the File Provider drive is this: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/blob/master/API/DW.Androidapi.JNI.FileProvider.pas

If anyone can help me I will be sooo grateful.

Below I will leave my AndroidManifest.template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="%package%"
        android:versionCode="%versionCode%"
        android:versionName="%versionName%"
        android:installLocation="%installLocation%">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="%minSdkVersion%"        
    android:targetSdkVersion="%targetSdkVersion%" />
    <%uses-permission%>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="%persistent%" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="%restoreAnyVersion%" 
        android:label="%label%" 
        android:debuggable="%debuggable%" 
        android:largeHeap="%largeHeap%"
        android:icon="%icon%"
        android:theme="%theme%"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="%hardwareAccelerated%"
        android:resizeableActivity="false">

        <%provider%>
        <%application-meta-data%>
        <%services%>
        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="%activityLabel%"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="%libNameValue%" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        <%activity%>
        <%receivers%>
    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

Now my AndroidManifest is:

> ```
> <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
>
> <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
> <application android:persistent="False" 
>     android:restoreAnyVersion="False" 
>     android:label="ART_Dinamica" 
>     android:debuggable="True" 
>     android:largeHeap="False"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
>     android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
>     android:resizeableActivity="false">
>
>     <provider
>         android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
>         android:authorities="com.embarcadero.ART_Dinamica.fileprovider"
>         android:exported="false"
>         android:grantUriPermissions="true">
>         <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
> ```
>
> android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
>
> ```
>     <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
>          This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
>     <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
>             android:label="ART_Dinamica"
>             android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
>             android:launchMode="singleTask">
>         <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
>         <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
>             android:value="ART_Dinamica" />
>         <intent-filter>  
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter> 
>     </activity>
>
>     <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.rtl.notifications.NotificationAlarm" />
>
> </application> </manifest> <!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
> ```

My provider_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Deployment image

[image: Deployment]

Comment: Have you checked the checkbox for the Secure File Sharing option in the Entitlements section of the Project Options?

Comment: Yes ... =\  marked or unmarked from the same ...

Comment: I updated my post, there is a new error. If you can read please ...

Comment: Can you check the Deployment Manager to make sure that the provider_paths.xml file is being deployed?

Comment: This you were asking for? I put a picture in the post

Comment: Uncheck the first one in the list

Comment: Tested here, same error =\

Comment: I unchecked what is like "type" file. I put my provider_paths.xml so you can make sure everything is correct

Comment: Just to clarify, I meant uncheck the first provider_paths.xml. You may need to uninstall the app, do a Clean and Build

Comment: I updated the deployment print in the post. About re-installation, I formatted my notebook a few weeks ago and had to re-install delphi. Is it really necessary to reinstall it? Since it wasn't that long ago that I installed it (maximum 2 weeks)

Comment: I meant uninstall the Android app from the device

Comment: Oh yes, every time I make a new version of the app I uninstall and install it again. So this should not be the problem. =\

Comment: A question that may be silly: Doesn't provider_paths have to be "interal-path"? Since I am trying to insert the PDF inside the APK? Another thing: If this doesn't work at all, do you know any other way I can open a PDF? Even if it's via an online link ... (because I need to deliver this Thursday)

Comment: [This SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49200962/delphi-10-2-how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application) has answer that you can follow to use intents to open a web page.  It will work with pdf as well - e.g. `http://somesite.com/your.pdf`.    His solution put it in Function form but you can do it however.

Comment: @user3602803 [This helped](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/1361-android-how-to-call-a-tjintent/) me figure out how to open a local pdf.  The key was down at the bottom about using `LUri := TAndroidHelper.JFileToJURI(TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(AFileName)));` instead of the `file://` approach...

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes down to a missing entry in the provider_paths.xml file that is generated by Delphi. In order for your scenario to work, the file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <files-path name="files" path="." />
</paths>
```

One solution is to modify the original provider_paths.xml file so that it contains the missing entry, add it to the projects deployment ensuring that the remote path is res\xml\, and **uncheck the deployment for the original**.

Given that the PDF being deployed is called sample.pdf, and is deployed to .\assets\internal, this code will open the PDF if a viewer is installed:

```
uses
  System.IOUtils,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.Helpers, Androidapi.JNI.Net, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
  LFile: JFile;
  LFileName: string;
begin
  // NOTE: You will need a PDF viewer installed on your device in order for this to work
  LFileName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'sample.pdf');
  LFile := TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(LFileName));
  LIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
  LIntent.setDataAndType(TAndroidHelper.JFileToJURI(LFile), StringToJString('application/pdf'));
  LIntent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(LIntent);
end;
```

I've put together a test app that does what I've described, here:

https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/MiscStuff/blob/master/Test/OpenPDFTest.zip

Comment: I've also filed a report in the Quality Portal, here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-26950