# How to open a link in a floating action buttom in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I have a floating action buttom in a fragment, and I want when it is clicked open an Internet page but not how to do it.
 I hope you can help me and n ose if it affects the fab is in a fragment thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2201999/7178860) can solve your problem. You just need to find your view (in this case a float action button) and set a clickListener for it.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);

        fabButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_button);
        fabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            });

        return rootView;
    }
```