# Android Studio with Clickable CardView redirect to website

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm new to Android Studio Programming.
I created CardView menu. But all i wanna do is, when you click the cardview it's redirect you to browser and open url (example, you press the cardview and redirect you to google.com website).
How to do it ?

My current code :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public CardView menu1, menu2, menu3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);
        menu1 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card1);
        menu2 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card2);
        menu3 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card3);

        menu1.setOnClickListener(this);
        menu2.setOnClickListener(this);
     menu3.setOnClickListener(this);
       
    }
    

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.card1:
                i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

as you can see, on menu1 it redirect you to another activity, but i want to do with menu2 and menu3 to open link. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: you can find your answer here ->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2201999/10429009

Answer (score 0):

Best method is to use `Uri.parse` as an `Intent` in your `switch` like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i;
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.card1:
            i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(i);
            break;
    }
}
```