# How can i close a built-in web browser that I have opened it by code in Android?

Tags: java, android, browser, webbrowser-control

Simply, I have used the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application) to open a URL in the Android's built-in web browser.

However, because I need to open many different URLs, I want to open and close the browser for every URL (instead of opening tabs).

**Code for open a browser:**

```
try {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(download_link));
startActivity(myIntent);
 } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No application can handle this request."
    + " Please install a webbrowser",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

I mean that my app can open a browser, and give the URL to load the website. However, if I give another URL, it will open as a new tab on the same opened browser. I do not need this especially when I want to run thousands of URLs. I want to open the browser and close it for every URL using my app. Is it possible?
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Build-in? No. You dont say so. Its just a browser on your device. Not build-in your app or Android.

Comment: `.... that I have opened it by code ...` You mean that you opened using ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: You mean that you opened using ACTION_VIEW. :: YES.
I mean that my app can open a browser, and give the URL to load the website. However, if I give another url, it will open as a new tab on the same opened browser. I do not need this especially when I want to run thousands of URLs. I want to open the browser and close it for every URL using my app. Is it possible?

Comment: Please edit your post instead of telling your problem in comments.