# How to filter string array (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android development.

I'm making a qr code scanning application, I'm trying to filter the scan data and see if it's a link, but I don't know how to do this because I'm very new to kotlin. Does anyone have a solution for this question?

I want to filter the browsing data, if there is "https" in the scan result, I want to open the link on chrome automatically

Comment: Use `.contains` https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/contains.html

Comment: If there is or begins with "https"? Also there are many libraries that already do this for you, do you actually want to implement this yourself for learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  for (i in scanned_list.indices) {
       single_scanned_value = scanned_list[i]
       if (single_scanned_value.contains("https")){
           //open browser.
       }
       break;
    }
```

For open browser, follow this link:
https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin-android/android-open-url-in-browser-activity/

Comment: Use filter instead of for/if.

Comment: the problem about filter tool is that the final list could contains a lot of values, and if I have well understood the problem, user want to open browser of the first link finded.

Comment: Your for loop will also open all links in the list, not only the first one. If you want only the first one, use find.

Comment: I did try this answer also works.Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

up

```
val list = listOf("I'm happy", "https:are you happy?", "no one is")
list.first { item -> item.lowercase().contains("https") }.apply { 
        doSomething(this)
    }
```

for open link inside Chrome just follow the answer here -> [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Comment: the problem about filter tool is that the final list could contains a lot of values, and if I have well understood the problem, user want to open browser of the first link finded.