# Create Icon(Bookmarklet) in Android to open a site in default browser

Tags: android

In Windows, if I have to create a custom icon to trigger a program, I can simply right-click on desktop/folder->New->Shortcut, and then fill in the necessary details, like "`chrome.exe www.example.com`".

Once created, when I click on this icon, it will directly open the site example.com in the Chrome browser in a single click.

I want to achieve this similar custom shortcut icon creation in Android, like a bookmarklet (or whatever it is called).

Ideally, when tapped/clicked, this icon should open the given site (say example.com) in the default browser of the Android phone.

This SO thread has some inputs ([How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)), but it does not have info about creating a Android icon which can be placed on Android phone's homescreen.