# How works exactly a popup in mobile apps?

Tags: android, html, popup, android-webview

[image: Example of the popup (Spotify)]

I'd like to know how dynamic popups work on mobile applications. Are there any api calls to be made in order to retrieve the information, and how to customize the display? When we click on the button, the application redirects us to a website, so is there necessarily a link in there, or is the popup just html?

My idea is to create a back to add the customize popup and save it with the brut code html in database and when app mobile call an API to get it. I don't know if it is the best practise.

Comment: Creating a popup in an android application is part of android UI, if you are looking to open a web URL from your application using a button click or anything, you can use intent. Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application